# how to display time and date with internationalization?

Tags: android, date, time, internationalization

```
private void updateClock() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
        Date d = new Date();
        day.setText(sdf.format(d));
        clock.setText(String.format("%tR", System.currentTimeMillis()));
        if (RS != null) {
            if (RS.adDue()) createAd();
        }
    }
```

How to implement internationalization into this to remove language barriers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

You should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
Locale currentLocale = new Locale("en", "US");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDatFormat("EEE MMM dd", currentLocale);
```

or:

```
Locale currentLocale = new Locale("fr", "CA");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd", currentLocale);
```

You can find more information about the different supported locales [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). Make sure you import java.util.Locale

EDIT: [This page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html) is also helpful and gives some concrete examples.